# Serving assets from port 81 and relative paths

Tags: javascript, nginx, port, relative-path, assets

I have one PHP app running on localhost port 80 and another running on port 81.

Pointing the browser to `http://localhost` runs the first app and all of its js, CSS, images in the `/assets` folder. However, the 2nd app only can serve js, CSS, images that have the *exact* file name as the 1st app. If the 2nd app's assets are in the 2nd app's `/assets` directory and don't have the same name as files in the first apps `/assets` folder, then those files aren't found you get a `404` error.

Here are more specifics on what I'm seeing:

**`http://localhost`**

```
<script src='/assets/foo.js'></script>
//file contents
alert('foo'); when foo.js is in app #1's /assets directory
```

**`http://localhost:81`**

```
<script src='/assets/foo.js'></script>

alert('foo 2'); //alerts "foo 2" when foo.js is in app #2's /assets directory

<script src='/assets/bar.js'></script>
//file contents:
alert('bar'); //file not found 404 error when bar.js is in app #2's /assets directory
```

Comment: Please include your config.

Comment: @TanHongTat my nginx conf?